# Explorer.exe crashes whenever I try to open a network computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

I have a Windows 10 computer that is experiencing some unusual problems accessing networked computers and devices.

If I go to "This PC" (My Computer) and expand the "Network" section in the left-hand navigation bar, I can see all of the computers on our network. However, if I double click on the icon for one of those networked computers, explorer.exe will crash, I temporarily lose the start bar and then moments later explorer.exe restarts.

I captured a dump of the crash and this is the stack:

```
Count:    1
Exception #:  0XC000027B
Stack:        
    KERNELBASE!RaiseFailFastException+0xae
    combase!RoFailFastWithErrorContextInternal2+0x27b
    Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x359bb
    Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x35733
    Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x35629
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x24c4a
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x24c8a
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x185d9
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x18310
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x18582
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x1f831
    twinapi_appcore!PsmInitializeExtension+0x1f8e6
    combase!WindowsTrimStringStart+0x2ba
    Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x35bb9
    Windows_UI_Xaml!GetStringRawBuffer+0x6ddb
    Windows_UI_Xaml!DllCanUnloadNow+0x1145de
    Windows_UI_Xaml+0x223ef4
    Windows_UI_Xaml+0x223c31
    USER32!CallWindowProcW+0x4f4
    USER32!DispatchMessageW+0x1bc
    combase!RoGetApartmentIdentifier+0x264
    combase!RoGetApartmentIdentifier+0xf2e
    combase!CoAddRefServerProcess+0x81f
    combase!CoAddRefServerProcess+0x715
    combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xcb
    Windows_UI_XamlHost!DllCanUnloadNow+0xd032
    Windows_UI_XamlHost!DllCanUnloadNow+0xd569
    SHCORE!GetDpiForMonitor+0x15d
    KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
    ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

It would appear that `Windows_UI_Xaml` is causing the crash somehow, but unfortunately that DLL seems to be a pretty central part of Windows 10. Googling for issues with the DLL and crashes related to networked computers has turned up nothing.

For what it's worth, this computer also cannot find any of the shared networked printers on my network and I've been unable to get it to join the "Homegroup" to share devices. I do not have these problems for other computers on the network.

Any ideas on the root cause of the crashing? Any suggestions for additional troubleshooting steps?

Comment: your system has been damaged. try running (from an elevated prompt) `sfc.exe /SCANNOW`.

Comment: @FrankThomas I ran sfc /scannow as an Administrator and got this message: "Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.log..." CBS.log is almost 13MB in size with not much discernible analysis contained within. What would you recommend for next steps?

Comment: Probably backup and rebuild. Its the most surefire approach. I'd start with a diskcheck, and evaluate the health of the hard disk from SMART stats. if its failing, then a replacement is in order. A RAM failure could also cause the issue, so a test with the MS memory diagnostic couldn't hurt. If the disk is healthy and the filesystem scan doesn't fix the problem, then you will have to try to repair it with restore points, or more probably a backup and rebuild.